# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011: create address records with a dialog

Tags: process, dialog, dynamics-crm-2011

within Microsoft CRM 2011 online, my goal is to enable the user to create any amount of address records with a dialog. My problem is that I cannot create an instance of the address entity from within the dialog.

I tried to create a dialog with address as primary entity but I cannot select the address entity to assign the values entered by the user. This makes sense to me, since an address cannot exist without a contact or account, if I understood that correctly.

If I create a dialog for a contact and collect values for the address, I cannot add a new address to the contact, since the contact entity does not have a reference to the address collection. I am not talking about the two addresses that are already part of the contact entity. I do understand that those are treated in a special way.

How can I create a dialog that creates a new address and adds it to a contact or account?

Comment: Really not sure why you're getting downgraded on this. It's a valid question in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for that. I do not understand the downgrades either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to achieve this via a dialog I'm afraid it's not possible straight out of the box. Addresses are kind of "special" in how they behave. You could probably achieve what you're looking for with the support of 1 or more Custom Workflow Activities to create the address record when it saves. But even at that I've seen it not behave exactly as you'd expect unless you set it up 100% correctly.

To be honest, I would question why you're trying to add addresses in this manner? The simple reason being I don't think it's going to make the system any more usable for you, or make address entry any easier. Adding an address (beyond the Address1 and Address2 fields) to a contact isn't terribly difficult, you just click on "More Addresses" and add a new address.

So my answer would be to stick with what's out of the box unless it's completely necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Our goal with adding addresses in this manner is to add more than two addresses in the dialog. Since we do not use the denormalized addresses (number 1 and 2) on the contact/account/lead entity, we have to find a way to add the additional addresses anyways. But I understand your proposal and I will discuss this approach with my product owner. Thanks for this hint.